# Path Problems Again with El Cap 10.11.6?

Tags: mactex, paths, updating

Last year I updated my mac to El Capitan, and followed the instructions [here](https://www.tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf) to fix the path issues. It was easy!

Today I updated to 10.11.6. The preferences in TeXMaker (my GUI of choice) reverted back to their pre-El Cap settings, and so naturally nothing compiled. I followed the same instructions as before, but this time the fix did nothing.

I tried running latex and pdflatex in terminal, and the commands are not found. On my macbook air that is running 10.11.1, both TexMaker and compiling in terminal work fine.

Any ideas? I don't understand enough about /usr/local/ vs /Library/TeX/ to know how to proceed.

Update: I have now discovered that the folder /Library/TeX/texbin has disappeared after updating to 10.11.6.

Moreover, the TeX Distribution pane in the system preferences won't load and produces the error ``Could not load the TeX Distribution preference pane".

I found [this](https://tug.org/mactex/newfeatures.html) possibly irrelevant remark about the Distribution preference pane in MacTex-2016; or at least I think it's irrelevant because I am sure I have MacTex-2015 installed. So, I tried to check this in TeXLive Utility, but I couldn't get that program working either.

In short **I can no longer find my TeX distribution**

Strange. I'll try reinstalling MacTex and update again. Thanks folks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I didn't update yet. I'll try tomorrow and report back.

Comment: I don't use TeXmaker, but I have updated to 10.11.6 and I do not have problems with paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling MacTex (using MacTex-2016) solved the problem.